# Not able to connect to the Virtual Box VM created by DevCloud

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I have installed DevCloud on MacOSX as per the instructions given in the link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/DevCloud
After Importing the image in Virtual Box and starting the VM, I am not able to ping the VM from my Host OS(Mac Machine). I have not changed any configuration and the default IPs are assigned in the VM.
i.e. 192.168.56.10 to Xenbr0 and the rest are not configured as only XenBr0 is given in /etc/network/interfaces
following is the exact output of ifconfig and eth0 and eth1 are not configured
[image]

What may be causing the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

That version of devcloud is a bit dated. Check out devcloud4 https://github.com/imduffy15/devcloud4

Specifically the binary-install-basic and binary-install-advanced.